# How to group by categoryid and display subtotal at the end of rows of each category in C# linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am working on a datatable. I want to get the **Subtotal** for each category and **Grand Total**.

I want to add the subtotal row at the end of rows of each. My problem is that I don't get the subtotal for the last category. I don't know where I went wrong.
Any one who can help me please.

Required output:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|CategoryID  |  Category  |  Orgname   | Penalties | Interest | Admin |TotalAmount|
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   1        | 1-Food     |   Spar     |  $10      |  $0      | $15.3 |  $20.3    |
+-------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   1        | 1-Food     |Pick n’ Pay |  $0       |  $10     | $20   |  $30      |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   Subtotal                           |  $10      |  $10     | $30.3 |  $50.3    |
+-------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   2        | 2-Auto     |  BMW       |  $0       |  $30     | $55   |  $85      |
|   2        | 2-Auto     | Toyota     |  $9       |  $0      | $14.5 |  $23.5    |
|   2        | 2-Auto     | Jaguar     |  $22.8    |  $8.2    | $50   |  $81      |
+-------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   Subtotal                           | $31.8     |  $38.2   | $119.5|  $189.5   |
+-------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   3        | 3-Banking  |  Absa      | $0        |  $40     | $155  |  $190     |
+-------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   Subtotal                           | $0        |  $40     | $155  |  $190     |
+-------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
|   Grand Total                        | $41.8     |  $88.2   | $304.8|  $429,8   |
+-------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------+-----------+
```

My code:

```
var query = (from _transaction in _entities.Transactions
             join _cd in _entities.Organisations on _transaction.Refno equals _cd.Refno
             join _category in _entities.Categorys on _transaction.CategoryID equals _category.CategoryID
             group new { _trans = _transaction, cd = _cd, } 
             by new { _transaction.CategoryID, _transaction.Refno, _cd.Orgname, _category.Description } 
             into _group
             orderby _group.Key.CategoryID
             select new
                { CategoryID = _group.Key.CategoryID,
                  Category = _group.Key.CategoryID + " - " + _group.Key.Description,
                  Refno = _group.Key.Refno,
                  Orgname = _group.Key.Orgname,
                  Penalties = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.Penalties),
                  Interest = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.Interest),
                  Admin = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.Admin),
                  TotalAmount = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.TotalAmount),
                 });
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(query.CopyToDataTable()); ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    //Get Subtotal
    long _CategoryID = 0; double Admin = 0; double Interest = 0; 
    double Penalties = 0; double TotalAmount = 0; string Title = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString().ToLower() != dt.Rows[i - 1]["Category"].ToString().ToLower())
              {
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow(), i);
            dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"] = _CategoryID;
            _CategoryID = 0;
            dt.Rows[i]["Category"] = Title;
            Title = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows[i]["Admin"] = Admin;
            Admin = 0;
            dt.Rows[i]["Interest"] = Interest;
            Interest = 0;
            dt.Rows[i]["Penalties"] = Penalties;
            Penalties = 0;
            dt.Rows[i]["TotalAmount"] = TotalAmount;
            TotalAmount = 0;
            i++;
            }
        }
        Title = "Subtotal";
        _CategoryID = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"]);
        Admin += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("Admin") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("Admin"));
        Interest += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("Interest") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("Interest"));
        Penalties += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("Penalties") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("Penalties"));
        TotalAmount += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("TotalAmount") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("TotalAmount"));
    }
    // Grand Total
    var subtotal = query.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryID).Select(s => new
    {
        CategoryID = s.Key,
        ISub = s.Sum(x => x.Interest),
        ASub = s.Sum(x => x.Admin),
        PSub = s.Sum(x => x.Penalties),
        TASub = s.Sum(x => x.TotalAmount)
    });
    var GrandTotal = subtotal.Select(s => new
    {
        GI = subtotal.Sum(x => x.ISub),
        GA = subtotal.Sum(x => x.ASub),
        GP = subtotal.Sum(x => x.PSub),
        GTA = subtotal.Sum(x => x.TSub)
    }).Distinct();

    //add grand total row to datatable
    foreach (var a in GrandTotal)
    {
        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Category"] = "Grand Total";
        dr["Interest"] = a.GI;
        dr["Admin"] = a.GA;
        dr["Penalties"] = a.GP;
        dr["TotalAmount"] = a.GTA;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical mistake when implementing grouping with a single loop. In such case the last group is not processed and requires some code duplication after the loop.

That's why I prefer a nested loop approach. You get the key, initialize aggregates, process until the key is changed and consume the group.

Applying it to your specific case would be something like this:

```
//Get Subtotal
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Initialize
    long _CategoryID = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"]);
    double Admin = 0; double Interest = 0;
    double Penalties = 0; double TotalAmount = 0; string Title = string.Empty;
    // Process    
    do
    {
        Admin += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("Admin") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("Admin"));
        Interest += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("Interest") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("Interest"));
        Penalties += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("Penalties") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("Penalties"));
        TotalAmount += Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].IsNull("TotalAmount") ? 0.0 : dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("TotalAmount"));
        i++;
    }
    while (i < dt.Rows.Count && _CategoryID == Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"]));
    // Consume    
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow(), i);
    dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"] = _CategoryID;
    dt.Rows[i]["Category"] = "Subtotal";
    dt.Rows[i]["Admin"] = Admin;
    dt.Rows[i]["Interest"] = Interest;
    dt.Rows[i]["Penalties"] = Penalties;
    dt.Rows[i]["TotalAmount"] = TotalAmount;
}
```

Comment: when I am using this way in more than a million records in database it just keeps onloading it doesn't stop.

Comment: You mean the above code? The performance shouldn't be different from your original code (it's only fixing the last group issue).

Comment: Let me know if it is inside the above `for` loop.

Comment: yes the problem is inside the `for loop`  is it possible to add the new datatable read `var Category = (from DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows
                            select new
                            {
                                CategoryID= dRow["CategoryID"],
                                Category = dRow["Category"]
                            }).Distinct();
            ds.Tables.Add(category.CopyToDataTable()); ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Table2"; DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[1];` then my `for loop` be like `for(int i=0; i<dataTable.Count; i++)` is that possible?

Comment: (2) Sure it is possible, why not. Hope outside of the loop :) (1) To clarify the situation, I'm pretty sure the performance issue is not caused by the new structure of the loop. It might be caused by the `Rows.Insert` - I've noticed that, but the question wasn't how to optimize the whole thing. In general, the whole table, subtotals and grand total can be generated with single pass over the query result. But that's another story.

Comment: Thanks Sir for that explanation. You the best.